# Invalid date literal

Tags: sql, teradata

```sql
SELECT 1 
FROM UDMTOOL_STG.GLOBAL_APPLE_BRAND_QUERIES main 
INNER JOIN UDMTOOL_STG.GLOBAL_APPLE_BRAND_QUERIES_TEMP temp
    ON (
            COALESCE(main.COUNTRY_CD,'X')=COALESCE(temp.COUNTRY_CD,'X') 
        AND COALESCE(main.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL,'X')=COALESCE(temp.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL,'X')
        AND COALESCE(main.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG,'X')=COALESCE(temp.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG,'X')
        AND COALESCE(cast(main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as DATE), DATE 'X')=COALESCE(cast(temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as date), date 'X')
        AND COALESCE(main.BRAND_NAME,'X')=COALESCE(temp.BRAND_NAME,'X') 
        AND main.OP_CODE<>'D'
    );
```

> Syntax error: Invalid DATE Literal.

when I run the query, it is throwing as syntax error
please suggest how to resolve the error?

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: `'X'` cannot be converted to / treated as date.

Comment: Please don’t spam the database tags. I removed the conflicting tags so you can add the one database where you are facing this error.

Comment: @June7 The error message tells that this is Teradata.

Comment: I want date, if date is not available then it should be X

Comment: Are you possibly trying to do an outer join here?  It kind of looks like with all those coalesces.

Answer (score 1):

> `AND COALESCE(cast(main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as DATE), DATE 'X')`

What kind of date value do you expect to get from `X`? SQL is a strongly-typed platform, so you need an **actual date** here. Since this seems to be about comparing `NULL` values you can use a date that doesn't make any sense for your data... say something waaaay in the past before the company was even in business. It just needs to be a *real date*:

```
AND COALESCE(cast(main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as DATE), DATE '1900-01-01')`
```

You could also write the comparisons to say what you actually mean:

```
AND (
   cast(main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as DATE) = cast(temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as date)
   OR (main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT IS NULL AND temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT IS NULL)
)
```

Better still if we can skip the `cast()` operations on one side. This will remove conversion operations for the value and allow index use. Both of these can have a **dramatic** impact on performance, so this isn't a idle thing.

Assuming the date casts on the `EFFECTIVE_START_DT` columns are just to remove the time portion from datetime fields, and not because you have **broken** schemas using varchar/string columns *pretending* to be dates, we can do this:

```
AND  ( 
    (main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT >= cast(temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as date) 
       and main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT < ( cast(temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT as date)  + Interval '1' day) )
    OR coalesce(main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT, temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT) IS NULL
)
```

and it should perform *significantly* better.

Comment: When date is not available i want to show as X

Comment: @anji Do that in your client code or reporting tool.  SQL is a strongly-typed platform. If you have a `date` column, you can only use `date` values. At very least you can save the conversion for the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to join on NULLs. Are you sure all these columns are nullable?

The recommended way in Teradata is (similar to Joel Coehoorn's answer) an explicit

```
 ON ( main.COUNTRY_CD = temp.COUNTRY_CD                             OR (main.COUNTRY_CD IS NULL AND temp.COUNTRY_CD IS NULL))
AND ( main.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL = temp.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL         OR (main.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL IS NULL AND temp.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL IS NULL))
AND ( main.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG = temp.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG OR (main.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG IS NULL AND temp.SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG IS NULL))
AND ( main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT = temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT             OR (main.EFFECTIVE_START_DT IS NULL AND temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DT IS NULL))
AND ( main.BRAND_NAME = temp.BRAND_NAME,'X')                        OR (main.BRAND_NAME IS NULL AND temp.BRAND_NAME IS NULL))
AND ( main.OP_CODE<>'D' );
```

Caution: ORed join-conditions normally lead to bad plans (forced product join), but in this case the optimizer transforms it into a special equality operator that compares NULLs as equal.